# Javascript (react native) - Use getter from outer scope

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is my first post on this amazing helpfully website, and I hope my question will help people such so many did for me.

I'm coming from Python, C/C++, Java, etc, and I'm a total noob in web-dev. I'm trying to develop an application with React Native but I have some troubles.

In languages that I practice, we usually use getters to return an attribute from a class from another class.
And that's what I'm trying to do with my application.

Let's say I Have this class :

```
class FacebookLogin extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.isFbProfileLoggedIn = false;
    this.accessTokenOfFbProfile = "";
  }

  getFbProfileLoggedIn() {
    return this.isFbProfileLoggedIn;
  }

  getAccessToken() {
    return this.accessTokenOfFbProfile;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <LoginButton
        readPermissions = { readPermissionsOnFbProfile }
        onLoginFinished = {
          (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              alert(strErrorLogin);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
              alert(strErrorLogin);
            } else {
              this.isFbProfileLoggedIn = true;
              console.log();
              AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
                .then( (data) => {
                  this.accessTokenOfFbProfile = data.accessToken;
                  alert(this.accessTokenOfFbProfile.toString());
                });
            }
          }
        }
        onLogoutFinished = { () => alert("Logged out.") }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

So, when I call to the getters methods inside the class that returns me the real value of the attribute, but when I'm calling to the getters from outter scope it only returns me the first value they had, never their real values. Plus, when I replace attributes for global variables and I do the same processus, it works like a charm.

Could you please explain me why and how to do it without global variables?

Thank you very much in advance! And please excuse my noobism :/

Comment: Which methods are we talking about here? And what do you mean by outer scope?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that the problem is that the `this` reference in the function it's not the same to the Class instance. Try binding the function with the current instance. Like this

```
class FacebookLogin extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.isFbProfileLoggedIn = false;
    this.accessTokenOfFbProfile = "";
    this.onLoginFinished = this.onLoginFinished.bind(this);
  }

  getFbProfileLoggedIn() {
    return this.isFbProfileLoggedIn;
  }

  getAccessToken() {
    return this.accessTokenOfFbProfile;
  }

  onLoginFinished(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      alert(strErrorLogin);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert(strErrorLogin);
    }
    this.isFbProfileLoggedIn = true;
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
      this.accessTokenOfFbProfile = data.accessToken;
      alert(this.accessTokenOfFbProfile.toString());
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <LoginButton
        readPermissions={readPermissionsOnFbProfile}
        onLoginFinished={this.onLoginFinished}
        onLogoutFinished={() => alert("Logged out.")}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: well it don't seem to work :/
btw, i call the get method inside a setTimeout function that is called inside the componentWillMount() of the main js file of the app.

Comment: Can you add a little example how you call it?

Comment: sure, i did something like that :

isFbProfileLoggedIn() {
    setInterval( () => {
      let a = fbLogin.stateProfileLoggedIn;
      console.log(a);
      }, 500);

------------------------------------------------

componentWillMount() {
    this.isFbProfileLoggedIn();

------------------------------------------------

And this will always print me false, except when I use global variables.